# Oauth2 authorization didn't provide authorization code from drupal site (oauth2 erver)

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have installed and enable the oauth2 server module in my drupal sit. When i try to authorize it redirect into the client app without authorization code.

Comment: show some code or try to elaborate more. What have you tried etc.